# Baked normals in substance painter doesn't look correctly in blender

Tags: shaders, normals, normal-map

Some edges look sharp, but I haven't made them sharp.
Auto Smooth - 57.3° (the same issue with any value)

After applying the baked normal maps from Substance painter in blender, the model looks like this:

[image: Cycles blender 2.93.1]

In Substance painter:
[image: Substance painter 2019.1.1]

Material nodes:
[image: Material nodes]

Wireframe and sharpen edges in blue:
[image: Wireframe]

Comment: are you sure it's not your topology that creates the problem? What does it give without any material? does the artefact remains?

Comment: I guess your normal map is still *DirectX* right? *Either* invert the green channel of your normal map using a RGB curve *or* just export as *OpenGL* from substance painter.

Comment: How to invert the green channel using the invert node: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TuXZI.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not certain it's responsible for your exact issues, but it looks like it may be, and it's something you should be doing anyways: Triangulate your model before painting in SP.

Blender and SP do not triangulate models the same way, and the triangulation affects the interpolation of UV across faces for any faces with any UV distortion whatsoever.

If your goal is to use a quad mesh in Blender, you can use SP on a copy of the model that has been triangulated using "fixed" mode triangulation, which is the default triangulation Blender uses at time of render for models that have not been explicitly triangulated up to that point.  You'll need to use custom normals on one of those meshes, copied from the other, so that SP and Blender are working on the same normals.

Comment: The problem was with Green channel in normal map and with non-triangulate geometry while importing to SP. Now it looks the same as in SP. Thank you!